# indicator of mosfet switch, optimized?

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, switching

I want a visual indicator of my MOSFET's switching state, so I've [designed this circuit](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/a3aam99k2yxq/mosfet-with-indicator/) with fairly generic smd parts and simulated it a bit to see if it performs as I've expected. It seems okay up to 4khz or so (and the usefulness of an LED breaks down at a few hertz anyhow).

Before I commit this to traces, is it designed appropriately? I'm not confident in my EE abilities.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQXSou.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### version two

resistor on base and LED on other side of NPN

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcGb6F.png)</sup>

Comment: Which is the "visual indicator", the lamp or the LED? What are the high and low voltages of CLK1?

Comment: I'm putting in the lamp as a proxy for some sort of load. CLK1 is 3v from a microcontroller- didn't know if there was a better way to specify it.

Comment: These are important details that should have been in your question from the beginning.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this world- I don't know what I don't know.

Comment: Then you provide as much information as you can. Recognize that the reader knows even less than you do.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an NPN transistor as a high-side switch, which is generally not a good idea. The NPN transistor should be between the LED's cathode and ground. You also need a resistor in series with the NPN base to limit the base current to a few milliamperes.

An easier approach would be to just put a 1k resistor and LED in parallel with the lamp. No need to add the NPN transistor at all.

Comment: I want the LED to work invariant of the load and whatever is on that side of the FET. Adding a 'fixed' NPN version now.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the gate voltage range is.  You show a square wave, but not the voltage levels.

If the highest goes much more than the 3 V supply for the LED, then that supply will be back-driven via the B-C junction.  That's probably not what you want.

Also, what's the maximum current the LED can handle?  Let's say that's 20 mA.  That means the maximum voltage across R_LED can be 2 V.  Let's say the LED drops 2.1 V, so that means the emitter should never go higher than 4.1 V, and therefore the base not higher than 4.8 or so.  However, as pointed out above, at about 3.7 V the 3 V power supply starts being back-driven.

In any case, you have to start with proper specs.  Jumping in an deciding on a topology doesn't make sense until you know what the job is that the circuit is supposed to perform.  Go back and do it right, starting with some real specs.

Comment: Sorry. I fixed the voltage (3v). I put the LED on the other side of the transistor, which I'd gotten wrong. I don't know what else I'm missing- it's a basic building block for a newbie, I hope.